# Angular service worker not running automatically without specifying interval

Tags: angular, angular-service-worker, service-worker-config, swupdate

My SPA is running in prod and i want to reload the page whenever a deployment is done. I can make this work by specifying interval to check for update every X minute but that won’t be the appropriate way.
Can anyone suggest how to make this work out to let service worker automatically tell my application that an update is available?

Answer (score 1):

You can send a push notification whenever there is a version change.

Your service worker can detect and handle it accordingly

https://developers.google.com/web/ilt/pwa/introduction-to-push-notifications